# Flutter hot reload only works for main.dart file

Tags: flutter

I create a new flutter project.

When I made some changes on lib/main.dart and press save. It will perform hot reload.

But when I made some changes on other files like lib/second.dart, the auto hot reload not working for me. I have to press hot reload button to reload.

Could any one tell me how to fix this problem.

The ide is Android Studio

and the flutter version is 3.13.7

flutter doctor runs good.

the ide can hot reload and the Perform hot reload on save is ticked.

Comment: solved by following this. https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/6996#issuecomment-1788041561

Answer (score 2):

in Android Studio Auto hot reload Edit these settings.

file -> Settings -> Editor ->Live Edit -> push Edit automatically.

Android Studio version  Hedgehog | 2023.1.1
[image]